# Nesting Laravel API search results from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Need some guidance on how to approach this:

PHP 7.2, Laravel 5.6 using API resources

I have a table of locations(location name, id, etc), and a table of reports. One (location) to many (reports). I'm using Searchy for the location search. When I search for a location, I want to include in the results, any reports that are also available for that location.

I believe this is a good case for a join, but Searchy can't do joins, so I'm trying to work around that. If there is a better approach I am all ears. BTW I'm new to Laravel so assume I know nothing.

```
        $response = Searchy::locations('location_name')->query($query)->get();

        // Add reports to array in each location result
        foreach($response->items as $location_row){
            $response->items[$location_row->location_id]->reports[] = Searchy::reports('location_id')->query($location_row->location_id)->get();
        }

        // Return the results

        return new LocationResource($response);
```

The specific error that I get is that the `items` array, is not available in the Collection object. Which it is, it's just private. Which tells me I'm doing this wrong.

Addendum: I am using Searchy for it's fuzzy search, if that isn't the best route and there are better alternatives I'm all for it.

**EDIT**
The response object (shortened):

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#497 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#491 (10) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(235)
      ["locality_id"]=>
      string(32) "102938098209384"
      ["locality_name"]=>
      string(7) "AREA 1"
      ["location_name"]=>
      string(10) "Station 10"
      ["location_id"]=>
      string(32) "098098019823909"
      ["location_address"]=>
      string(21) "xx.xx.xx.xx"
      ["location_last_update"]=>
      string(19) "2018-03-30 00:00:00"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2018-07-16 16:29:13"
      ["updated_at"]=>
      string(19) "2018-07-16 16:29:13"
      ["relevance"]=>
      string(2) "36"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what's inside $response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't got a way to test it around but try to switch the foreach cycle, something like this:

```
$response = Searchy::locations('location_name')->query($query)->get();
// Add reports to array in each location result
foreach($response as $locationKey => &$locationRow){
    $locationRow->reports[] = Searchy::reports('location_id')->query($location_row->location_id)->get();
}
// Return the results
return new LocationResource($response);
```

One thing you can do to help you better visualize your needs, is to work with them as `Arrays`, and by that all you need to do is add `->toArray()` at the end of the `->get()` method (`get()` method is one of the methods that fetches data and returns a `collection`, `toArray` converts the `collection` into an `array`)

Edit: According to Searchy, you can manipulate the query object so I'm guessing you can add your joins

> You can use getQuery() instead of get() to return an instance of the Database Query Object in case you want to do further manipulation to the results

I think in this case, you may benefit from EagerLoading. Not sure if Searchy allows it but when it comes to queries, I usually either opt by using Laravel's ORM if I can, or write them out with QueryBuilder, and it's pretty straight forward

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Let's say you've got these 2 Models, **Location** and **Report**

```
class Location extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [/*An array that contains a list of fields of your table*/];
    //When you do Locations::create($arrayOfData);, Laravel will do insert into ($fillables) values ($arrayOfData). 

    //Hidden means they'll be hidden whenever you fetch an object type of Location
    protected $hidden = ["created_at","updated_at"];

    //Here, we establish a relationship this model has to reports
    //You can further down and set custom to what are the foreign keys and local keys on the link above
    public function reports()
    {
      return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Report");
    }
}

class Report extends Model {
    protected $fillable =['id','location_id',...];
    protected $hidden = ["created_at","updated_at"];

    public function reports() {
          return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Location");
    }
}
```

The query would be:  `Location::with('report')->get();`

Comment: Bam yeah that worked. Im sitting here thinking "that wouldn't work, it would just create a new variable instead of updating the original object", and then I look up the ampersand and it all makes sense now. Thanks!

Also, I am using the JsonResource in my models, can that still work with eager loading? Because that looks exactly like what I need and would save immensely on queries. I only need the fuzzy searching to resolve location names.

Comment: Glad you got it to work! I tried to left an example on how it works but the documentation explains it better. Yes, you can, but I'll start a chat with you because of some attention you'll need